# Is it a good a practice to patch all calls within the method when creating a unit test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Supposedly, I have the following class. Just using this as an example.

```
class Connect:
   def __init__(ip_address):
      self.ip_address = ip_address

   def get_ip_address():  
       return self.ip_address

   def tcp_connect()
      ip = self.get_ip_address()  # I know you can use self.ip_address but this is an example 
      conn = TcpConnection(ip)
      return conn
```

If I want to create a unit test for `tcp_connect()`, I will definitely patch TcpConnection(). Since `get_ip_address()` is a simple method call, is it a good practice to patch it or it is not necessary at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.get_ip_address()` is part of your unit under test, so no, you'd not mock that out.

Only mock things that are outside your 'unit', in this case the class you are testing. `TcpConnection()` is outside the unit, methods on `Connect` are within it.

Comment: Are unit-tests useful for testing python APIs? They are costly (to write and maintain), so what's their value if I have many integration tests? I love unit testing; just curious on greatest benefits.

Comment: @PythonForEver: unit tests are your bread and butter! They are the quick tests, the things that your IDE could run automatically even when you save a file, in an ideal scenario. Integration tests generally take longer, require more resources, and are not as easy to debug when a bug occurs. Also, unit tests are much better for covering a wide range of possible scenarios, especially when using fixtures, and so make it far easier to debug very specific issues in isolation.  Personally, I find integration tests are much harder to write and maintain, if done correctly.